# I'm getting this error when opening any UI flow. Resource not found for the segment 'flowsessions' . Any idea why?

Tags: power-automate

I'm getting this error when opening any UI flow. `Resource not found for the segment 'flowsessions'`.

I've created a flow which is calling a UI flow (web) which is failing with the same error.

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 1):

UI Flow is not yet GA, still in Preview.

[MSFT response in Forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/I-Found-A-Bug/Resource-not-found-for-the-segment-flowsessions/td-p/423714) clearly state that there are limitations & issues related to this error:

> If you are using the UI Flow in a Flow, it will needs install on-premise gateway and the gateway only supported in default environment, so the UI Flow only supported in default environment, in the new environment you can only create it and test it.
>
> The UI Flow still in preview, please wait until the feature is rolled out everywhere, be patient to some known issue solved.